# Is there a macOS Salesforce SDK?

Tags: mac-os-x

I find the iOS SDK which is in ObjC...

Is there a macOS SDK?  Could the iOS SDK be used (with mods) on macOS?

Brand new to Salesforce development but I'm looking to build both mobile and desktop version of an app for the Apple ecosystem.

Answer (score 3):

There is no "official" (i.e. software specifically developed by salesforce.com) desktop SDKs for Salesforce. However, you can use [Simon Fell](https://twitter.com/superfell)'s [SDK's](https://www.superfell.com/) and other open source software (FOSS) to get started. Specifically, you could choose to use ZKSforce to access Salesforce in both iOS and MacOS.

Comment: Thanks for this information!  Seems to be what I am looking for.